# Using VBA to Change Text Style in All Tables in a Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to change the **text style** inside all tables in a document, and then bold the text in all columns of the first row. I currently have the following...

```
Sub AutoTableFormat()

Dim tbl As Table
For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    txt.Text.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Table Text")
Next

End Sub
```

The following give me an error saying Run-time error '5849': Could not apply the style. I am very new to VBA(just started today) and was hoping for some help. Honestly dont even know where to start with the bolding thing either. Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what the object `txt` should be. How about try `tbl.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Table Text")`

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Basic Editor provides you with three tools to help with coding:

1. Intellisense - shows you the available properties and methods for objects as you type.
2. Object Browser - allows you to browse or search the object model
3. Online help

Although you start out well with a loop through the tables the line inside the loop is completely illogical. What exactly is the variable `txt` supposed to represent? Where is it declared? What relation does it have to `tbl`?

Had you used the tools at your disposal you would have discovered that a `Table` object has a `Range` which has a `Style` property. This would have given you:

```
Sub AutoTableFormat()

    Dim tbl As Table
    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        tbl.Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Table Text")
    Next

End Sub
```

Setting the format of the first column is awkward as the `Column` object does not have a `Range`. This means you have to loop through each cell of the first column to apply the formatting. A more efficient way of achieving your goal would be to create a table style with all your required formatting and then apply that.

```
Sub AutoTableFormat()

    Dim tbl As Table
    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        tbl.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("My Table Style")
        tbl.ApplyStyleFirstColumn
    Next

End Sub
```